# Error 404 viewing a BIRT Report in a JSP page in Eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, http-status-code-404, birt

I am trying to run a BIRT report in a JSP, following [The BIRT documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-usage.php#tags)
Almost everything works fine: the report is correctly viewed in preview, but when I try to run the project and to show the report in the JSP I get a 404 error not found.
The web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
        <display-name>MktPortal</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <jsp-config>
            <taglib>
                <taglib-uri>/birt.tld</taglib-uri>
                <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld</taglib-location>
            </taglib>
        </jsp-config>
    </web-app>
```

The viewReport.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/birt.tld" prefix="birt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="v_venditedispre.rptdesign"
        pattern="frameset" height="450" width="700" format="html">
    </birt:viewer>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the error:
[image: 404 error]

Answer (score 0):

The BIRT will require BIRT runtime to render the rptdesign file.
The Taglib which you are using does not contain the runtime itself.

To test it properly just download the BIRT runtime war file and deploy into Web Server and place the rptdesign file into the proper path and then try to render it.

Link for BIRT runtime: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-4.8.0-201806261756/birt-runtime-4.8.0-20180626.zip

Once you deploy runtime into the same web server it will start working. Also, it is suggested to keep the reporting separate from the core application code.
This clearly means that create a single directory to store all reports and point the directory to pick the report file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I definitively switched to jasperreport, since BIRT seems to be abandoned or at least is very very little active and it is always very difficult to get help and infos.